# Send textarea data without encode using jQuery ajax POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I am sending textarea data using jquery post but it is sending data with encoded format, I tried by passing contentType but after sending contentType, encoded data is not showing in browser console, but at server side, I am getting encoaded data.
How can I send textarea text using POST method without encoding text.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/jyn79s7y/) is UI code what I did

I tried by sending data to web-service using postman plugin, and it responded with correct result, this means there is no problem with rest endpoint.

```js
$("#btnSend").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $("#txtBox").val(),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<textarea id="txtBox">Some Area</textarea>
<button id="btnSend">Send</button>
```

Comment: Can we have a code please ?

Comment: Close?? why?? specify reason

Comment: In what way is the data being encoded? What tools and techniques are you using to determine that it is being encoded in that way?

Comment: Server side data is in json format.

Comment: @LaxmikantDange — Since your JS is saying it expects the response to be in JSON format, that doesn't seem to be a problem. What is the problem?

Comment: @Quentin, when I send string using POST, it gets in encoded format. spaces are replaced by '+' automatically.